Evans's scalar conservation law order of operation? $\left( u_t + F(u)_x \right)$
This is a small question (taken from Evans's PDE book, page 8). I generally avoid writing parenthesis for a function operating on some character to its right. In absence of parenthesis, I read my order of operations from right to left.  For example, I would write
$$ g(f(x)) := g  \text{ } f  \text{ } x $$
When a character has superscripts or subscripts, then I interpret subscripts first, and then superscripts. I'll have $\partial_x$ represent taking the derivative of some function w.r.t $x$. Given my habits, would I interpret the term
$$ F(u)_x  $$
as
$$ \text{(i)     } \quad \quad F \left( \partial_x \text{ } u \right)  $$
or
$$ \text{(ii)     }\quad \quad \partial_x \text{} \left( F  \text{ } u \right)$$
I searched online and couldn't find a direct answer or webpage for this question. I only want a direct answer on whether (i) or (ii) is the correct interpretation. Thanks in advance.

Clearly, it is (ii). There are several papers on these equations where it is written more clearly. I will link them. I also dislike the Evans-Notation (which is e.g. also used by Alberto Bressan, who is one of the most important researchers in this field).
The equation is supposed to "conserve mass", if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(t,x) = 0$ and $F(0) = 0$, i.e.
$$
\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u(t, x)~\mathrm{d}x \equiv 0.
$$
Formally, this is because
$$
\tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} u~\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\partial_t  u ~\mathrm{d}x = - \int_{\mathbb{R}} \partial_x \big(F(u(x)\big) ~\mathrm{d}x = -F\big(u(x)\big) \bigg \vert^{\infty}_{-\infty} = 0.
$$
Some papers:
Amorim et al., Coclite et al., Andreianov et al. and MANY MANY more.
The $\mathrm{div}$-version is the $n$-dimensional generalization of the conservation law you mentioned.
